# How to scroll the emacs Buffer List window via the keyboard

Tags: emacs

After invoking the **list-buffers** via C x C b we have the Buffers Window in the lower pane of the emacs window

- What are the shortcuts to toggle between the editor windowand the Buffer List window
- Inside of the buffer list window: what are the keyboard shortcuts to scroll through the list?
- (I assume that once the proper one were highlighted then pressing  would activate it)

[image]

**Update**

Per a suggestion:  I used C-x h to show the help topics. How do I navigate out of the Command Mini-buffer into the top-window displaying the help options?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `C-h m` in the buffer to find out what the important keys do.

`C-v` and `M-v` scroll windows, but it seems that you really mean move the cursor through the lines of the buffer, which is `C-n` or `<down>` (the down arrow).

`C-x o` selects the other window.

(You should follow the Emacs tutorial (`C-h t`), to learn the basics of moving around etc.)

Comment: I awarded this, but basically the keys were working erratically: no new info was learnt here. Specifically the buffer list was not behaving like other windows - C-x o was not working properly.  I had gone through a number of tutorials, help pages, google searches,  etc already , as well as customizing emacs in a few ways including setting up CUA mode: so mentioning basic help was not so necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it appears, that you lack knowledge of the emacs fundamentals. I suggest to follow the emacs tutorial, which you can either acces via the menu bar or via `C-h t`.

Comment: Basically the keys were working erratically: no new info was learnt here. Specifically the buffer list was not behaving like other windows - C-x o was not working properly.  I had gone through a number of tutorials, help pages, google searches,  etc already , as well as customizing emacs in a few ways including setting up CUA mode: so mentioning basic help was not so necessary.

Comment: The way you formulated your question indicates that you have not read the tutorial. Your bullet point questions are basic commandos, which are explained in the tutorial.